# Create access point on debian intel 5300 agn

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, access-point, hostapd

i'm using debian jessie on a dell latitude e6400 with a intel 5300 agn wireless card, i've found many guides on the web but none worked as far, but they all refer to hostapd as an valuable tool, so, can anybody give me the basics to create an access point on debian jessie using hostapd??

Answer (score 0):

To create a sw access point you can use airbase-ng:
http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airbase-ng